# Ruby Dashing: Issues with Jobs (on a CentOS Server)

Tags: ruby, centos, sinatra, dashing

I'm having a weird event occur, where my dashing dashboard's list widget is showing erroneous data. Here's the screenshot from my live Dashing widget

**Erroneous Widget**

[image]

**Expected Output**

[image: Expected Output]

What follows is the code for the widget:

**Code in .erb**

```
<li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="2" data-sizey="6">
 <div data-id="facebook_insights" data-view="List" data-unordered="true" data-title="Facebook Insights: Weekly Post Views" data-moreinfo="Updated every 10 seconds"</div>
</li>
```

**Code in job .rb**

```
require 'mysql2'

social_count = Hash.new({ value: 0 })
time = Time.new()

date_time1 = Time.new(time.year, time.month, time.day-1)
...

SCHEDULER.every '10s' do

begin

db = Mysql.new(<HOST>,<USER>,<PASS>,<DBNAME>)

mysql1 = "SELECT <VAR> FROM <TABLE> WHERE <VAR> = '#{date_time1}' ORDER BY <VAR> DESC LIMIT 1"
...

result1 = db.query(mysql1)
...

rescue

ensure
 db.close
end

result1.each do |row|
strrow1 = row[0]
$value1 = strrow1.to_i
end
...    

social_count[0] = {label: "1:", value: $value1}
...

send_event('facebook_insights', { items: social_count.values })
end
```

What is really baffling, is that this code works for a similar widget using different data in the SQL query. Can anyone help me understand why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked and re-checked the data and in my other, working code, I had my `$value` variables defined as `$valueX` with X being the number. I thought to myself "Maybe the variable names are getting confused due to them having the same name", so I changed my code to

**Working Code**

```
result1.each do |row|
strrow1 = row[0]
$variable1 = strrow1.to_i
end
...    

social_count[0] = {label: "1:", value: $variable1}
```

Et Voila! Eureka! It worked. Not sure why it still got confused with the names, but from now on, my names will be unique!